# Use Google speech to text instead of Apple's

Tags: macos, applescript, google, voice-dictation

Google currently has much higher quality speech transcription. You can try it easily by going to [doc.new](http://doc.new) and pressing `Cmd-Shift-S` and talking. Compare to using the built in system from Apple (pressing `Fn` twice).

Ideally there would be a good way to do this, but if that doesn't work, hacky is the next best thing. An AppleScript or Hammerspoon script that instantly pops up a Google Docs window, and then inserts the result is better than nothing.

Given that things like this https://dictation.io/speech exist, or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/o1vuzs8z/) it seems like it should be possible to at least have an extension that can interface with other applications to enable dictation input, but I haven't found any yet.

Is there any way to somehow use this instead of the built in transcription, e.g. with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-gcloud  This is the reverse of what you need, but essential steps are the same https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382620/how-can-i-use-cloud-based-text-to-speech-services-as-native-voices-in-mac-os/382733#382733

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Voice In Speech to Text Chrome Extension](https://dictanote.co/voicein/). It builds on Google's speech to text to allow you to dictate directly on many websites like Gmail, Wordpress, Zendesk, Facebook, etc. Note: it works only in the Chrome browser.

You can download from the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-in-voice-typing/pjnefijmagpdjfhhkpljicbbpicelgko?hl=en)