# Is there a way to convert an audio to text using terminal?

Tags: command-line, audio, text

I have 2000 audio files named as audio1.wav, audio2.wav, etc.

Each file contains one or two words like "house", "car", "beach house", etc.

Is there a way to read the audios and convert them to text using terminal, so I can use the result to rename the files?

PS: I'm aware of [How can I use cloud-based text-to-speech services as native voices in Mac OS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382620/how-can-i-use-cloud-based-text-to-speech-services-as-native-voices-in-mac-os/382733#382733) but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't involve Google.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-gcloud https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382620/how-can-i-use-cloud-based-text-to-speech-services-as-native-voices-in-mac-os/382733#382733

Comment: sorry but I do not want to use google.

Comment: Well then get a trained a model from GitHub which can do the conversion for you https://github.com/search?q=speech+recognition

Comment: This will work: https://github.com/openai/whisper. Alternatively, you can use this: https://github.com/petewarden/spchcat